# How to do union of multiple CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two queries as below

**Query 1**

```
set @sql = cast(N'
;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.enddate) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.enddate as date), s.enddate) DayTime,
    s.enddate SalesDate,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),OrigionalSubTotal/100.0) as OrigionalSubTotal,
    o.ordertype ordertype
  from sale s,DinePointOrderType o
  where s.enddate >= @DateBegin and s.enddate < @DateEnd
 and o.ordertypeindex = s.ordertype
 and s.ordertype = 1
  and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0
  and s.IsCancelled = 0 and s.wasrefunded=0
),
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(
  select
    p.hrs,
    p.period,
    isnull(p.ordertype,''DINE IN'') ordertype,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + N'
  from #Timing t
  cross join #WeekDays w
  left join cteSales s on datediff(hour, w.wd_date, s.SalesDate) = t.hrs
  pivot
  (
    Sum(s.OrigionalSubTotal)
    for w.wd_name in (' + @pivot_val_per_day_list + N')
  ) p
)

select
  r.hrs,
  r.period as [From-To],
  r.ordertype,' + @sum_cols_per_day_list + N'
from cteSalesPerWeekDays r
group by r.hrs, r.period,r.ordertype
order by r.hrs

'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime',
  @DateBegin = @DateBegin,
  @DateEnd = @TradeDateEnd

GO
```

**Query 2**

```
set @sql = cast(N'
;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.enddate) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.enddate as date), s.enddate) DayTime,
    s.enddate SalesDate,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),OrigionalSubTotal/100.0) as OrigionalSubTotal,
    o.ordertype ordertype
  from sale s,DinePointOrderType o
  where s.enddate >= @DateBegin and s.enddate < @DateEnd
 and o.ordertypeindex = s.ordertype
 and s.ordertype = 2
  and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0
  and s.IsCancelled = 0 and s.wasrefunded=0
),
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(
  select
    p.hrs,
    p.period,
    isnull(p.ordertype,''TAKE OUT'') ordertype,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + N'
  from #Timing t
  cross join #WeekDays w
  left join cteSales s on datediff(hour, w.wd_date, s.SalesDate) = t.hrs
  pivot
  (
    Sum(s.OrigionalSubTotal)
    for w.wd_name in (' + @pivot_val_per_day_list + N')
  ) p
)

select
  r.hrs,
  r.period as [From-To],
  r.ordertype,' + @sum_cols_per_day_list + N'
from cteSalesPerWeekDays r
group by r.hrs, r.period,r.ordertype
order by r.hrs

'


exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime',
  @DateBegin = @DateBegin,
  @DateEnd = @TradeDateEnd
```

Is it possible to do a union of this two queries?

Comment: Post your attempt to perform the UNION, and what error you are getting so that we can help debug your effort.

Comment: @TabAlleman edited my question

Comment: The reason for the error is that you close your first `CAST(` function after `''Dine In''`.   And you don't re-open another for `''Take Out''`

Comment: @TabAlleman is the place where iam puting union is correct?

Comment: If you fix the CAST() error, does it work?

Comment: unable to fix not getting the proper place of cast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115738/discussion-between-sachu-and-tab-alleman).

Comment: @TabAlleman when modified new error..

Comment: Why do you use 2 ctes if you can use just one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a new CAST on this line:

```
  isnull(p.ordertype,''DINE IN'') ordertype,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + N'
```

Like this:

```
  isnull(p.ordertype,''DINE IN'') ordertype,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + CAST(N'
```

EDIT, and now with that error fixed, your UNION is in the wrong place.

You cannot UNION two CTE's like this:

```
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(...)
union
cteSales as
(...)
```

You can only use UNION between two SELECT statements.   So you could make Dine In and Take Out versions of your CTE's and then UNION them in the final select like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM cteSalesPerWeekDaysDINEIN
UNION 
SELECT ...
FROM cteSalesPerWeekDaysTAKEOUT
```

Comment: is it possible to show with above two queries? please

Answer (score 0):

So much code... that could be done simply with PIVOT and dynamic SQL.

Create tables to test output:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ordertypes (
    ordertype_id int, 
    name nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Ordertypes VALUES
(1, 'DINE IN'),
(2, 'TAKE OUT'),
(3, 'DELIVERY')


CREATE TABLE #Sale (
    StartDate datetime, 
    Amt money, 
    ordertype_id int
)

INSERT INTO #Sale VALUES
('2016-06-12 10:01:15.780', 10.00, 1),
('2016-06-12 10:15:57.360', 20.00, 1),
('2016-06-12 12:48:41.250', 50.00, 2),
('2016-06-13 12:04:45.090', 15.00, 3)

CREATE TABLE #time_intervals (
    tStart time,
    tEnd time
)

;WITH time_intervals AS (
SELECT  CAST('00:00:00' as time) as tStart,
        CAST('00:59:59' as time) as tEnd
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(hour,1,tStart),
        DATEADD(hour,1,tEnd)
FROM time_intervals
WHERE tEnd < CAST('23:59:59' as time)
)

INSERT INTO #time_intervals
SELECT *
FROM time_intervals
```

Main query:

```
DECLARE @dateFrom date = '2016-06-12',
        @dateTo date = '2016-06-13'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columns nvarchar(max),
        @cast_columns nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cast_columns= STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(CAST(StartDate as date)) +',0.00) as ' + QUOTENAME(CAST(StartDate as date))
    FROM #Sale
    WHERE CAST(StartDate as date) between @dateFrom and @dateTo
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),
    @columns = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(StartDate as date))
    FROM #Sale
    WHERE CAST(StartDate as date) between @dateFrom and @dateTo
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @sql = '
SELECT  LEFT(tStart,5) + ''-'' + LEFT(DATEADD(second,1,tEnd),5) as Interval,
        Name,
        '+@cast_columns+'
FROM (
    SELECT  tStart,
            tEnd,
            ot.name,
            CAST(StartDate as date) as sDate, 
            Amt
    FROM #time_intervals t
    CROSS JOIN #Ordertypes ot 
    LEFT JOIN #Sale s
        ON CAST(s.StartDate as time) between t.tStart and t.tEnd and ot.ordertype_id = S.ordertype_id
) as p
PIVOT (
    SUM(Amt) FOR sDate IN ('+@columns+')
) as pvt
ORDER BY Name, tStart'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
Interval    Name        2016-06-12  2016-06-13
00:00-01:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
01:00-02:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
02:00-03:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
03:00-04:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
04:00-05:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
05:00-06:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
06:00-07:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
07:00-08:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
08:00-09:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
09:00-10:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
10:00-11:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
11:00-12:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
12:00-13:00 DELIVERY    0.00        15.00
13:00-14:00 DELIVERY    0.00        0.00
...
09:00-10:00 DINE IN     0.00        0.00
10:00-11:00 DINE IN     30.00       0.00
11:00-12:00 DINE IN     0.00        0.00
...
11:00-12:00 TAKE OUT    0.00        0.00
12:00-13:00 TAKE OUT    50.00       0.00
13:00-14:00 TAKE OUT    0.00        0.00
14:00-15:00 TAKE OUT    0.00        0.00
```